# How to extend _mm256_permute4x64 to AVX-512?

Tags: simd, avx512

I have this AVX2 code which I'm trying to extend to AVX-512:

```
_mm256_permute4x64_epi64(a, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));
```

The extended code would look like this:

```
_mm512_permute8x64_epi64(a, _MM_SHUFFLE(7, 5, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 0));
```

But this intrinsic doesn't exist.

The intent is to take the low 64-bit part of each 128-bit lane and pack them together in the bottom 256-bit part of the register.

How can I extend the original code to AVX-512?

Comment: Basically this doesn't exist because the shufmask wouldn't fit in 8 bits, but there are shuffles that can do this that take an index vector

Comment: If you can efficiently use 512-bit vectors later, you might as well use `vpermt2q` to take the elements you want from *two* input vectors and pack them into `__m512i`.  (`_mm512_permutex2var_epi64` with a control vector.)

Comment: Especially for finding shuffle instructions, you can very often compile a simple program with a `set`/`setr` instruction and ask clang what shuffle instruction it comes up with: https://godbolt.org/z/PE86MeE8s (Indexing happens to work with `epi64` due to the way `__m512i` is represented in gcc/clang.)